# Control structure of document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document, in which is stored information about products. Each chapter has a small table inside it with three rows: `Price`, `Description`, `Image`. Here is how it looks:

[image]

I want to change the order of rows in all these tables. Or alternatively, I want to add an additional row to each of them. So the desired result should be:

[image]

An explanation of how it could work:

- We need a database (Access/Excel/CSV) to store information about each product:

  [image]
- We need to somehow tell Word in which order display the rows. I found something close here:

  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj889465.aspx - See example with "Harry Potter" and "Learning XML".
- Then we need to insert this into Word. Fields are the first thing which came to mind:

  ```
  Product A

  { InsertProduct A }

  Product B

  { InsertProduct B }
  ```

I don't understand how it could be done. Using only VBA? Using custom content controls? Do I need to connect Excel/Access to this document?

Comment: Please explain. You have tabels in Word documents and you want to make database from them? And how do you want determine quantity?

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec I want somehow control the structure of all these tables, across all the document. Do you use styles? Using the styles, you can control the colors, fonts and margins through all your document. I want the same thing to control the structure (i.e. the order of rows in product's tables and add/remove rows in each table). I don't know how it could be done. I don't sure I really need database for it. I mentioned databases just because I *assume* it could be necessary for this task.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to have data structured in Excel worksheets, not in the Word document. So, my first proposal is to ask your partner from the client side or from the other department to provide you data in Excel. If is not possible, you can copy tables from MS Word to MS Excel. Let's assume, that tables are like you have showed and everyone is preceded with product name. I have adapted one of my macros for you:

```
Sub CopyTablesFromWord()
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim docFile As Object
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rngToCopy As Range
    Dim cl As Object
    Dim wdRow As Object
    Dim wdCell As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tblRw As Object, tblCl As Object

    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set docFile = wdApp.Documents(1)
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    For Each tbl In docFile.Tables
        Set rngToCopy = ws.Range("A" & ws.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        With rngToCopy
            .Value = "Product"
            .Offset(, 1).Value = tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Previous.Paragraphs(1).Range
            Set rngToCopy = .Offset(1)
        End With

        i = 1
        For Each tblRw In tbl.Rows
            j = 1
            For Each tblCl In tblRw.Cells
                rngToCopy.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value = tbl.Rows(i).Cells(j).Range
                j = j + 1
            Next tblCl
            i = i + 1
        Next tblRw

    Next tbl

End Sub
```

This macro reads all tables from the Word document and copy them to the Excel workbook. 
Note, I have assumed that product name is just one line before each table. You may need amend this macro for your purpose. As you have data in the spreadsheet, you can use another subroutine to vlookup product name, price, description or whatever and add arrange them in your table or database.

I cannot tell you how you can add quantity to this, because I don't know where are you taking it from.